# How to make this transposing algorithm read a whole text file

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption

So I've been trying to write a transposing algorithm where each character’s position is shifted to a new location within a file. For example if the key is 3 and the character array is

```
"This program is supposed to encrypt a file."
```

after encrypting, the output will be

```
"Tsrr  ps  cpai.h oaispetert lipgmsuodony fe"
```

The problem is that after it's done encrypting the first line of a file, it stops and doesn't continue encrypting the whole file. after compiling, it can be executed like this

```
./executable -e 3 inputfile outputfile
```

.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 200

int main ( int argc, char* argv[ ] ) {
    int pos = 0;
    char characters[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
    int index, k, size, key;
    char* echars;
    FILE* input;
    FILE* output;


    if ( argc == 5 ) {

        // exits if key is lower than 1
        key = atoi ( argv[ 2 ] );
        if ( key < 1 ) {
            perror ( "Error: This value cannot be used as a key" );
            exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        input = fopen ( argv[ 3 ], "r" );

        //Shows error if there's no file
        if ( input == NULL ) {
            perror ( "Error, File doesn't exits" );
            exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        output = fopen ( argv[ 4 ], "w" );
        fgets (characters, BUFFER_SIZE, input);
        fseek (input, 0, SEEK_END);
        size = ftell ( input );
        echars = ( char* ) malloc ( size );




        if ( strcmp ( argv[ 1 ], "-e" ) == 0 ) {
        while (strlen(characters) && characters[strlen(characters)-1] == '\n'){
         characters[strlen(characters)-1] = '\0';
            for (index = 0; index < key; index++) {
                for (k = index; k < strlen( characters ); k += key)
                     echars[ pos++ ] = characters[ k ];
            }
            printf("Successfuly encrypted\n");
            }

        } else if( strcmp ( argv[ 1 ], "-d" ) == 0 ) {
            for (index = 0; index < key; index++) {
                for (k = index; k < strlen( characters ); k += key)
                     echars[ k ] = characters[ pos++ ];
            }
            printf("Successfuly decrypted\n");
        }

        fputs( echars, output );
        fclose ( input );
        fclose ( output );
    } else {
        perror("Too few arguments, something went wrong\n");
        printf("Usage: ./program -e (encrypts) or -d (decripts) 3 (key) inputfile destinationfile\n");
        printf("Example:'./exectutable -e 3 inputfile.txt outputfile.txt\n");
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no loop for reading. You just read one line, "encrypts"/"decrypts" it and then you're done. Either read line-by-line in a loop, or read all using `fread`.

Comment: where is a loop with `EOF` condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fgets` stops reading when it hits a newline.

You need to either put a loop around it or use a read operation that can read larger chunks.

Comment: How do you read multiple lines with fgets? I have just learned how to use it but I'm not a pro yet, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: `while (!feof(input)) {  fgets(buffer, size, input); ...`

Comment: If you want to read multiple lines in one read operation use `fread`.

Comment: So in my code, it would be like this `while (!feof(input)) { 
   fgets (characters, BUFFER_SIZE, input);
   
   }`? But it only prints 1 character and breaks the whole encyption

Comment: Oh ok, I'm going to research about fread and see what I can come up with

Comment: The `...` should be replaced with code to encrypt the read line and print it to the output file.